# Format for c3.js

Tags: python, c3.js

I have a dataframe that outputs the information i want from python and pandas will convert it to json as below, what is the best format for c3.js to read it in?

```
'{"schema": {"fields":[{"name":"Employee Department","type":"string"},
{"name":"Total_Employees","type":"integer"},
{"name":"Completed","type":"integer"},
{"name":"Remaining","type":"integer"}],"primaryKey":["Employee Department"],"pandas_version":"0.20.0"}, 
"data": 
    [
    {"Employee Department":"AQPSD","Total_Employees":163,"Completed":70,"Remaining":93},
    {"Employee Department":"ASD","Total_Employees":149,"Completed":77,"Remaining":72},
    {"Employee Department":"CO","Total_Employees":37,"Completed":8,"Remaining":29},
    {"Employee Department":"ECARS","Total_Employees":243,"Completed":158,"Remaining":85},
    {"Employee Department":"ED","Total_Employees":172,"Completed":70,"Remaining":102},
    {"Employee Department":"EO","Total_Employees":70,"Completed":24,"Remaining":46},
    {"Employee Department":"ISD","Total_Employees":138,"Completed":54,"Remaining":84},
    {"Employee Department":"MLD","Total_Employees":180,"Completed":101,"Remaining":79},
    {"Employee Department":"MSCD","Total_Employees":161,"Completed":79,"Remaining":82},
    {"Employee Department":"OIS","Total_Employees":93,"Completed":41,"Remaining":52},
    {"Employee Department":"RD","Total_Employees":79,"Completed":38,"Remaining":41},
    {"Employee Department":"TTD","Total_Employees":102,"Completed":45,"Remaining":57}]
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `df.to_json(orient='records')` where `df` is your dataframe, the data is serialized in the JSON format that c3.js expects.

Assuming that you are using something like Flask, your controller can return that json, and your front end can make a call to that route (say, using `$.ajax()`). Then when you receive the payload, you can use `JSON.parse()` on it as pass it directly to your c3.generate function like so:

```
        c3.generate({
                data: {
                    json: // here is where your data goes
                }
        });
```

Comment: what file is this in, how do i get my json output after json : // would it be just json: http://10.94.0.153:5000/sans_data ?